# where to learn ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I went to an interview early today and it came out that I don't like php.
I was instructed by the 2 wonderful interviewers to consider ruby on rails
They explained a feature that a forum can be created within 15 mins.

My question is does anyone know any good tutorials for anyone who is a complete beginner to ruby on rails? 
Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: I learned by doing all this http://astonj.com/tech/best-way-to-learn-ruby-rails/ (it is also returned with the !learn factoid helper in the official Ruby on Rails chat room)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tutorials online, but didn't really get what I wanted until picking up a couple books.  These are my favorites.

- [Programming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby)
- [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)
- [The Rails Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321445619)
- [The Rspec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book)

Answer (score 3):

Go straight to http://railsforzombies.org

Very high quality online tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [The Official Web Page](http://rubyonrails.org/). A few clicks from there lands you at the [Online Course](http://railsforzombies.org/)

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://www.buildingwebapps.com/learningrails or http://railscasts.com is a good source of information.

Answer (score 0):

Like NewB said, I'd go with [Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example](http://zfer.us/wthPa) (affiliate link if you buy it, you can also read it online for free!). It's a very good introduction for complete beginners to web development, as it mentions git for version control and basic SQL stuff.